# Inheritance from .NET class in PowerShell

Tags: .net, powershell, inheritance, collections, subclass

I have an application where I am using a HashSet from `System.Collections.Generic.HashSet`, but would like to add functionality to it.

I'm attempting to use class inheritance to make a subclass of `HashSet` but am failing miserably.

I must be declaring the class name incorrectly but can't find other examples that inherit from  collection type classes.

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

class StatusBucket : System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[HashSet[object]] {
    [array] toArray() {
        $array = [object[]]::new($this.count)
        foreach ($value in $this) {
            $array.Add($value)
        }
        return $array
    }
}

$setValues = @('1', '2')

$testHashSet = [HashSet[object]]::new($ids) # Works as expected
Write-Host $testHashSet

$testStatusBucket = [StatusBucket[object]]::new($ids) # Fails
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else ends up in a similar situation I eventually figured it out.

Instead of specifying the type for the set as you would in C# like `<T>`, you can do the same with brackets. You can also omit the namespace if you have imported it as you would normally in the script. So the class signature looks like this:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
class StatusBucket : HashSet[Object] {
}
```

My second problem was that I was having trouble instantiating my new class. After some digging I figured out that constructors do not inherit automatically. In order to use the base class constructor you need to use  `: base()` like this:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
class StatusBucket : HashSet[Object] {
    StatusBucket() : base() {}
    # or to use additional arguments
    StatusBucket($oneArgument) : base($oneArgument) {}
}
```

So in this case the final result with my additional method ends up looking like this:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
class StatusBucket : HashSet[object] {

    StatusBucket() : base() { }
    StatusBucket($collection): base($collection) { }

    [array] toArray() {
        $array = [object[]]::new($this.count)
        $this.CopyTo($array)
        return $array
    }
}
```